# Feature Request: See deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

How about we allow people with reputation >= 5000 to see deleted questions & answers?

Comment: I just broke 5k, so part of me likes this, but I'm still going to have to downvote you unless you can provide a better reason than "it's a fun ability to have." Are 10k+ users not doing enough janitorial work?

Answer (score 5):

Why would they need to? 10k users can see deleted posts, but that's because they also have the ability to vote to undelete them, which is hard to do if they're invisible. If users can't undelete posts there's no reason for them to see deleted posts in the first place

Comment: I just think it's a fun ability to have, even if you can't delete them. Just today, someone told me that Jon Skeet answered on my question and then deleted his answer. I would like to see his answer, even if he deleted it. Why? Call it curiosity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290847/canonical-tolist-in-java/4290864#4290864

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Michael Mrozek, people don't need to see ALL deleted question, but they should **always** be able **to see** their **own questions** that were deleted.

Expecially considering that questions are deleted without prior notice.

Comment: Then you may also like [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed your post is circa 2010; in 2018, you *can* see your own deleted posts, though it's difficult and not very centralized as it's on a per-site basis, and perhaps each site has different user IDs.

See **your profile** under the tabs for **questions and answers** and there are links to the deleted Q&As.
The links follow this format:
https://$CHANGEMETASITE/users/recently-deleted-questions/$YOURUSERNUMBER

I tried to post about it here in a related feature request:

[I want to see all my exchange linked deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317901/i-want-to-see-all-my-exchange-linked-deleted-questions)

Ironically, this question will probably be deleted too.