# I didn't receive the Altruist badge

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Maybe I'm confused about the criteria for receiving the [Altruist badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/64/altruist). I put some bounty on a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion) that I thought should be implemented. However as the time was close to running out and the number of upvotes had ceased to increase I thought I'd just award the bounty.

I also awarded the bounty on Stack Overflow just afterwards on a different question. Upon receipt of the [Benefactor badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/68/benefactor) I remembered the Altruist badge here on meta. However I don't seem to have received it.

**Edit**
Just to clarify. Does this mean the reason that the badge wasn't awarded was nothing to do with a delay? Should I have received the badge soon after awarding the bounty or is it an overnight job? I don't want to accept the wrong answer.

Comment: If you wanted the badge so badly then you weren't really that altruistic were you? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug when the question had no owner - this has been fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Badge scripts are run on a schedule. Wait 24 hours and if you still haven't got the badge ask then.