# Deletion notifications

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, search, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notice of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion)

I'd like to be notified when stuff I posted gets deleted, e.g. when I answered a question that was deleted (by a moderator or the user), commented on later deleted posts, or when comments of mine are deleted.

It seems mods like to [delete stuff that could actually be useful](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3618/where-has-the-comment-thread-on-page-file-stuff-gone-to). They might have a good reason to do so, but it's obviously not just spam, useless content and hopelessly wrong answers that are removed. And this doesn't even account for users that were able to delete their own questions after others contributed content.

I'd really like to be notified about such changes in a way that allows me to retrieve my content. There are (or were) even some rather lengthy comment threads I participated in and repeatedly read and used as groundwork for later answers. So losing access to stuff I wrote would not only annoy me (and have me wondering about my mental health), but could also prevent me from answering some questions.

I have repeatedly tried to use the site's search function and web search to find older comments and posts of mine without much success. Maybe I just suck at this, but it's also likely that some things were deleted for one reason or another, either by moderators or other users.

That's why I want to be notified not just about edits that change my content, but also about deletions that remove my content.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you can't even **search for your own deleted posts**, even if you have >10k privileges. Or that they are listed in your profile. It doesn't make sense to just show them when you happen to have the URL. Heck, I can't even search for deleted posts with certain URLs, which would make spam flagging more effective. But that's another story.

Comment: By the way, you know that you can see edits to your posts by going to *Profile → Responses → Revisions*?

Comment: @slhck I know, that's what I referred to about being notified about edits. That same view could use a new category deletions!

Comment: I know that posts are soft-deleted, with exceptions. However I know until recently comments could not even be seen by mods, and I am not sure if they can trigger delete notifications for comments. I do think deletes on posts however makes sense, and for some reason I think there is some notification for posts deleted by mods, but I will have to research what triggers it or where I saw mention of it.