# See activity on questions recently moved

Tags: support, deleted-questions, migrated-questions

How do I see a question I have proposed an answer to which may have been recently deleted or moved to another StackExchange site? I wanted to add to my answer wherever it ended up, but I can't seem to see it on my activity list.

Should it appear as deleted/redirected?

Comment: Is it by chance [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/620374/how-to-make-my-vim-recognize-filetype-and-load-the-corresponding-syntax-file/620375#620375)?

Comment: Nope, but I hope you didn't have to trawl superuser for it. Thanks for the effort though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1091386 shows some of what I was looking for. Not sure yet if it works for moved answers as well, but probably not.

Thanks, whoever implemented this!

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't migrated; the user who asked that question was deleted, and his questions with him. Not to go into too many details, but... You're probably better off not having wasted any further time on it. This particular individual has a *history...*

Comment: Thanks! But I would have liked at least a note in answers that the question was deleted, or something. Plus the question itself, independent of the asker, would have been useful on at least another Stack, right?

Comment: @icedwater it was [already requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80460/152859). Anyway if you got upvotes on that answer you should see it in your reputation history when ticking "show removed posts" as title only and "removed" notice.

Comment: Thanks @ShaWizDowArd for pointing out almost the same question with a different title :)

Comment: It didn't, I was planning to add detail to my answer but it went poof before I could. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to add to my answer wherever it ended up

For this you have the [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1098281/icedwater) which let you see your whole activity in the whole network in one place. To find answers you need to go to [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/1098281/icedwater?tab=activity) and in there you can click the "posts" filter:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! However as expected this didn't show the deleted question. So I guess it would still be nice to have that feature added.

Comment: @icedwater if you didn't get any upvotes I fear there's no way to see it indeed or find it, even with 10K rep. If it's important to you, just keep external record of all your posts. :)