# How to improve an answer, and being aware of moderators conduct

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderators, rejected-edits, review-abuse

I am asking your help to understand:

1. How can I edit one post which has one error, or, why I can't.
2. How can people be noticed when a moderator flags or deletes her
   comment or answer or edit which are correct, just because maybe they 
   need to earn one more badge.

Following some example.

About 1), my last contribution was [adding a minor edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4334854) to improve one answer which that way doesn't work. My answer is an actual fix. This can be demonstrated (sorry for being a bit technical here, but it's easy matter) by:

- [Reading the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7): The context has no *['field_name']* child, which is in fact *['field']['field_name']*.
- Checking the code of drupal, or trying whit a debugger (see following image).

[image: A screenshot from the debugger]

The three reviewer didn't spend a word to explain what's wrong, the message is clearly automatic (of course I'm referring to an existing post for making one edit!). And I haven't been notified about the fact my contribution was invalid (no way to control who control).

[image: The reviewers]

Although I am aware that my edit fix a little oversight, but, even if little it doesn't make the code work. This in the general picture of making SO a better and polished knowledge place, where people can find and exploit precise contributes... or maybe I'm wrong?

About 2), sometime ago a friend notified me that an [answer I gave on Chinese SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/chengyu-with-two-numbers/6070#6070) was deleted. She needed to read my answer again because of interest for her studies.
The answer was deleted without me being notified about. This means no way to prevent moderators to go around deleting past contributions for mistake or any other reason (nobody is perfect). That answer, even if arrived late, the moment it was deleted was already voted up three times, which in the S.O. ecosystem is signal of interest by the community. Maybe there is some way to activate notifications? Don't you think there should be a way, default to on, to control the conduct of moderators?

Looking forward to receive your suggestion on my two highlighted points, on how to safely and politely contribute to this community.

Comment: Regarding 1) you should comment to have the OP correct it themselves/to inform anyone else who may come across the post. Code edits other than those fixing obvious typos will usually get rejected - as they should.

Comment: Maybe that's because moderators are not supposed to know how to code? That'd make sense. Thank you, this is worth knowing (sorry, I can't +1).

Comment: Because your average 2k user (not moderator) is not expected to have enough knowledge of `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` to know that you know better than the OP. To prove it to us took a good 4 lines of text and a screenshot of web inspector. If you commented on the post, the OP already has enough specific knowledge to realise his mistake upon correction, and would likely thank you for pointing out the error and correct the post. I have enough rep that my edits do not get reviewed, but I would still have commented rather than editing.

Comment: Yes now it's perfectly clear, thanks for your help. 

S.O. help says: "Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.  Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post." But I didn't do this consideration.

Comment: `This means no way to prevent moderators to go around deleting past contributions, just e.g. to earn the clean up badge.` That is patently false and baseless.

Comment: e.g., = exempli gratia.

Comment: I am perfectly literate, thank you.  The cleanup badge is awarded for *rolling back an edit*, not deleting anything, and moderators do not (or would not for very long) go and delete posts to earn a badge.

Comment: Ok, first of all, -6 means this question is harmful and I'll delete. But I still don't know if there is a way of being notified when an answer is deleted _for mistake_ or for any other reason by a moderator. Cause according to my short experience, this happens.

Comment: If someone didn't leave a comment on your post, then raise that on the meta for the Chinese language site and someone can clarify the reason why for you.  It's unfair to make assertions about a system of rules when you're just starting to know the ropes.

Comment: I decided to post here cause I supposed it to be a more general question. I nevertheless tried to base my assertions on some tangible fact. But, thank you for your help and your considerations, that's what I asked to you all.

Comment: @OGHaza If the reviewer doesn't have sufficient knowledge to evaluate the change they should skip. There is no expectation that every reviewer be able to assess every review.

Comment: @donnadulcinea: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! See the [meta-help]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. Downvotes here mean people don't agree with the premise of your post.

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes in an ideal world, but the suggested edit review queue couldn't be further from ideal. I'm just being realistic.

Comment: @OGHaza - So if you accept in an ideal world edits that correct broken code should be accepted then why say "as they should" in your first comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Editing Code

There a [question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) devoted to the very topic of when you should edit code and when you should not edit code. It covers both questions and answers. For answers the currently accepted answer states:

> **Don't**:
>
> - ...
> - Change the code logic or functionality — even if you think you're correcting it

The question I linked to does not go into rationales but as I see it, here are the requirements for a proposed code edit to be an improvement:

1. The original code would have to be definitely wrong. If the original code is correct, why should it be modified in favor of code which is just as correct? We're not supposed to edit other people's posts just to bring them in line with our preferences.
2. The proposed code would have to be definitely right.

Even if the second point is easy to determine --- perhaps searching the doc or some sources is enough to find a canonical example that justifies the proposed change --- the first is where it gets more complicated. Libraries change, code changes, frameworks change. So something which was not possible becomes possible. Or sometimes the documentation is deficient. So the method of doing X which *is* documented may not be the *only* valid method of doing X. It has happened that I've looked at code I initially thought was wrong to discover (after a search) that it is in fact a new method of doing things or that it was there all along but the developers did not publicize it broadly. (And here I don't mean using a private API but something that the developers did not bother to put in the docs but that they have publicly acknowledged as a legitimate way of using their software.)

Then add to this the fact that the answer remains attached to the reputation of the person who answered, and that a bad edit may make them look foolish, and perhaps cost them reputation. The edit history is available but rare is the user who will bother with looking at the history to determine whether a fault in the answer was introduced by an edit.

If I'm going to err, I'm going to err on the side of not allowing the code change. The person who proposed the change can leave a comment explaining why they think the code in the answer is wrong. This is the best way for everyone to figure out whether the answer should be changed or not.

#### Notifications

That feature request has been [discussed here regarding edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor), and [here regarding deletions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion).

Given the history of these two questions, I'm not expecting it to change soon.