# Provide overview over own answers to deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, deleted-questions, information-display

Today I wanted to link an old answer of mine in a comment. I knew very well that I had written it and it gained a couple of upvotes, but no way I could find it! I've tried everything in the search, but no way. It also wasn't in the [answers lists](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi?tab=answers&sort=votes) on my profile. Not even Google did list it when searching for the topic, until on the fourth (or so) Google page I found an outdated scraper site that had the exact question title in its cache, but no link. With the exact title I could then hunt down [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610741/use-jquery-or-q-js-for-promises) eventually:

The question had been closed as off-topic and then got deleted. At least I could inspect it due to my >10k rep.

- There was [no notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80460/183280)
- There's a `show removed posts` checkbox on my reputation overview, but there was no rep loss because of that deletion.
- There's a [`recent deleted answers` link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1048572) on my answers overview, but my *answer* wasn't deleted.

I would like to have an overview (or at least a notification about) answers of mine that are no longer publicly visible. I often rely on material (links etc) from my old answers when forging new ones or answering comments, and it's quite annoying to have them silently vanish.

Even when the question was not suitable for StackOverflow, some of the (more popular) answers might even deserve to be moved to a blog post or similar to be still available on the web.

Comment: related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/183280)