# When Roomba deletes a question, add it to the “deleted recent questions” list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, auto-delete

When Roomba deletes a question, that would be great if the question always gets added it to the “deleted recent questions” list (or some other list). As of now, questions older than 60 days that Roomba removes do not appear in the list, so users who forget to keep tracks of links to their questions externally won't have a link to their prior question.

Comment: A question older than 60 days would not seem to qualify as a recent question so deleting it should not add it to the “deleted recent questions” list.  Adding it to a "recently deleted questions" would make more sense.

Comment: @PolyGeo That'd work too.

Comment: Except that there is no "recently deleted questions" [of any age] list or I suspect a need to implement one.

Comment: @PolyGeo ok.... perhaps to add questions deleted by roomba?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as the "recently deleted questions" page in one's user profile now lists *all* questions that were deleted within the last 60 days, regardless of when they were posted.

This was [announced in February 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343215/377214), but that announcement was deleted as it was posted to the wrong question. Unfortunately, no non-deleted announcement exists of this change.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that your motive for this is that Roomba often deletes old questions, even over year old, and the OP has no clue what happened to his/her question.

While valid point, the "deleted recent questions" is not the proper place in my opinion, since year+ is really not "recent".

Better mechanism in my opinion would be sending notification when a question of yours is deleted, no matter for what reason, which is already a popular feature request: [Notice of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion).

Comment: I agree, but since this feature has been asked forever and has never been implemented, I'm trying to find alternative options....

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt fair enough but this simply does not feel right. If there was a +1 for good intentions I would have given it, but that's not how things work here. :)

Comment: Got to get used to SE treating questions like crap.

Comment: Reminding people that something they've forgotten about was ignored by the entire community for a long period of time and then discarded doesn't seem like it would have positive results...

Comment: @Shog9 still better than starting to doubt yourself e.g. "hey, I am sure I asked this in the past. Where is it?? Or maybe I'm getting crazy?" :)

Comment: False dichotomy, @ShadowWizard. The goal of the "roomba" is to remove stuff that *no one* cares about anymore; to the extent that it succeeds, badgering folks about it is counter-productive; to the extent that it fails, badgering folks about it is not a solution. There is, somewhere, a solution that helps folks avoid second-guessing themselves *without* rubbing their faces in increasingly-ancient mistakes they can no longer correct... But this isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

Roomba deletions appear in the "recently deleted" list available in the 10k tools ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days)).  This is a list of deleted posts (both questions and answers) excluding self-deletions, most recent first.  I think there's a cap to the number of entries, as I've sometimes seen the list stop way before the selected time range would suggest, but I've never dug into that.  Unless your site has a *lot* of deletions, you should be able to see deletions for the last several days at least, up to 30 days on less-deletey sites.

Comment: Thanks. 1) why not making it available to anyone? 2) as far as I can see there is no way to spot questions deleted by roomba amongst the questions in the list, so it's not that helpful. I am mostly interesting in browsing my questions that got deleted by Roomba.

Comment: Yeah, that list isn't great for looking for any particular pattern of deletion -- you can't filter it at all and the UI has other issues.  I'm guessing the list is only available at 10k because, except for your own posts, under 10k you can't see what the post was anyway.  This list is mainly to allow the community to review activity; it's not designed for your use case.