# notify in inbox on deleted answer

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-answers

I noticed that one of my answers was deleted by a moderator (without comment) and I *never got any notice of the occurrence*.

[How can I profile C++ code running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143125/32453)

If we get notifications in our dashboard for things as small as single upvotes, it would nice to also be notified if answers we create are deleted, so we can respond to the occurrence (fix it up, etc.)

Comment: Just so you know the back story behind the post. That particular question was revived by Shog9 [when he did this wayward resource request rescues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/). That post was edited to not make it a resource request, and all the "link to tool" only answers were deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notice of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I delete a post, I try to follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) for ♦ moderators:

> Whenever possible, **try to leave frequent comments on posts where you’ve taken (or considered taking) a moderator action**, explaining the reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the norms of the community and the moderation policies.

Such a comment will give you a notification in your inbox, even if the post is deleted, making this feature request obsolete.

I would expect a comment in this case as well, since it's a rather high scoring answer. (I can *guess* why it's deleted, but I'll defer this to the Stack Overflow moderators.) Perhaps they were busy (the workload for Stack Overflow moderators is rather high) and forgot to leave a comment while rushing to the next flags. Maybe they even *left* a comment but it has been deleted since, who knows?

Comment: Yeah you'd expect a comment at least.  Sometimes questions are deleted "by machine" and I would like a notification there as well, FWIW.  Even if it's a machine generated comment, that would work :)

Comment: Adding a comment isn't that feasible when we're acting in bulk. I personally have deleted more that 60000 posts after becoming a moderator, and have left 23000 comments. I tend to leave a comment when the action which I've taken needs some data which is not visible to the community members.

Comment: True; there are some scripts which help with that (I estimate that 80% of the posts I delete have a pro-forma comment from [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061), but YMMV.) That question *could* use a comment (or subscripted text at the end of the body) explaining what happened to the many deleted answers; the history of that question is visible to all users but not evident. (This comment/edit won't notify the authors of the answers, but I digress; my answer is intending to show why this feature request is not necessary for *most* cases an answer is deleted.)

Comment: I'm not as worried about "acting in bulk" as with *somehow getting any kind of notification* as it were...I guess I am worried about "acting in bulk" if it causes notificationless deletions though, heh....

Comment: Yes, for those cases (which are relatively rare) your feature request would definitely help (which is why I upvoted it).