# Deletion notification

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, notifications

I just found out that one of my answers had been deleted 17 days ago. It had 18 up votes and I don't have the rep to see down votes, close votes, or whatever else would have notified me that it was subject to deletion. Also, it was deleted 2 weeks after originally posted. I tried to click the "undelete" link, but it said it couldn't be undeleted due to being deleted by a moderator.

I'm aware of these other Questions, but so far none of them have apparently done anything about a notification and the only thing I can find against a notification is SE/SO thinks they'll get "whiny" responses:

- [Answer deleted, without notice, no chance to improve etc.?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/answer-deleted-without-notice-no-chance-to-improve-etc/2303#2303)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work/)
- [When a user gets a post deleted by a moderator, does he still get notifications on the comments left on it during his absence?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284654/when-a-user-gets-a-post-deleted-by-a-moderator-does-he-still-get-notifications)
- [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work)
- [Send authors an inbox message if their question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-is-put-on-hold)

I hesitate to post a link to my Answer, since I'm well aware of the "Streisand effect", but here it is anyway:   https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23480/3616

There is a single comment about it's quality, but it doesn't mention deletion as a result of not following the "include backup" mention. It reads more as an informal suggestion, rather than a strict rules enforcement message. Even though it has 5 upvotes, I'm not sure I ever saw it with votes, and I wouldn't have been notified of those votes anyway. Even so, 5 votes for an informal edit suggestion vs 18 votes for it being a good Answer doesn't really strike me as worthy of deletion. I'm aware that it only takes 5 votes for close (or was that done after the 3 vote change, IDK), but there's no indication to me that the same people who voted for the comment voted to close/delete the answer, or that some people who didn't bother to vote for the comment voted elsewhere.

As others mentioned in their linked Questions, you just get a "surprise, you can't find your Question or Answer anywhere". As a web dev myself, this isn't good UI/UX.

The message box above my Answer just says that it was deleted, but not why, so I'm also essentially clueless as to what would make it better or if it could be improved to remove the deletion. Since there's no reason stated for the deletion, I don't know if it's been deleted for the same reason for the comment or not.

As mentioned in a linked Questions above, all the points I got for the Answer have been nullified, as if they never existed. My Reputation history tab doesn't show me getting (or losing) any points and my histogram of points also doesn't show anything. All obvious history for this Answer is wiped out as if it never happened, so unless I happen to notice the "deleted recent answers" at the bottom of the "Answers" tab, which I rarely go to, I'd never know there was an issue.

<s>I've spent so much time trying to figure out what happened and reading other Q&A's, I'm not sure how I found out it was deleted.</s> Oh, wait, I just figured it out. I went to my Network Profile and it's still listed there, for some reason. It's not even in my own profile's various lists of Answers I've posted, except for that hidden "deleted recent answers" link I've never seen before and didn't know to look for.

One of the Questions above mentioned that SE/SO doesn't want to spam people with close votes or deletions, yet I get notifications when a User is deleted. I also get notifications for when *I* down vote a Question or Answer. IMO, neither of those are useful notifications, but notification about deleted Questions and Answers sure seems like a useful notification to me, all the other people posting about it, and people up voting those posts. Besides, how many people would be getting spammed about their posts getting deleted? If a single user is making that many bad posts, they probably should be getting spammed.

**So my real question is**: What is the (real) reason why we aren't notified when something is deleted?

I have a feeling it's because SE/SO doesn't want immature comments defending the post, as someone mentioned in an Answer linked above. However, without those notifications, we often have no way knowing something's wrong. I know I don't sit on my Answers and refresh them every 5 min to see what's going on, especially weeks after it's posted. I'm not even going to sit on this Question waiting for a response.

If SE/SO doesn't want to spam people, at least notify them once they've hit the halfway point to a close/delete quorum as well as when it's actually acted on. I realize good Questions and Answers get random or malicious close/delete votes, so not everything necessarily needs a notification, but a half compromise between "nothing" and "spam" needs to be found.

**FYI,** I'm moving/re-asking this question here based on the comment made by EmC here:

https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/deletion-notification

As a side note, I didn't get any notification for the down vote on that question. I wouldn't have known it was received poorly without the comment. I remember getting down vote bubble notifications (as in -2 RP), but some months (I think) back they stopped. Now I have to click on the "Recent Achievements" icon to see them, though I didn't get that much notification for my Question above. To me, this sounds as if SE/SO wants to hide as much negative feedback from the user as possible, and just surprise them with it all when they go back to their post. Again, this doesn't seem like good UI/UX to, me as a developer or as a user.

---

After modification to include sources for backing my claims, my post was restored, however I also didn't get any notification for this either. The history of the up-votes "magically" reappeared in my timelines as if it had never been deleted. I'm glad it's able to be seen again (as well as the rep I regained), but I'm still confused as to why I haven't gotten any sort of notification about this sort of change. Deletion and restoring of posts seems like the type of major change users should get notifications for.

---

I just had another question deleted 25 days ago with no notifications.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222969/how-to-disable-compiler-warnings-in-only-generated-code-without-editing-the-file

This was deleted by Community. Evidently because it has -1 votes and I haven't constantly been updating it, the "Roomba" script decided I didn't need an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are users notified when a moderator comments on a post that is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301713/are-users-notified-when-a-moderator-comments-on-a-post-that-is-deleted) - Your *real* question above is "why weren't you notified about the deletion", but as [you linked to](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/deletion-notification#comment13353_3939) the moderator did explain (perhaps not perfectly) why. --- Why the "Achievements Notification" doesn't *light* for DVs is a different question, answer 2nd 2 last sentence.

Comment: @Rob, no that doesn't answer my question because I didn't see the same results, in that I have not received any notification at all about the deletion. I was truly surprised my question was deleted 17 days prior. I'm on SE/SO every workday for my job, so I would have seen the notification, had it happened.

Comment: That's [not unheard of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336409/looking-for-stats-related-to-possibly-coordinated-comments-flagging) as the user mentioned in that Q&A *received* multiple messages but *saw* none of them. You should consider adding the "support" tag if you want the staff to investigate

Comment: @Rob, I don't see how that thread had anything to do with notifications. It talked about moderators deleting comments and targeted flagging of comments by users. I'll add the Support tag, though.

Comment: @Rob For clarity, I commented Nov 19 and the answer wasn't deleted (by another mod) until Dec 2, so computercarguy had plenty of time to see the comment notification. The issue here seems to be why he didn't get a notification at the time the post was deleted.

Comment: @EmC We all dislike when there are problems with our Qs or As and like to be in the loop (no reference to the Blog), I'm supportive of there being such a delivery - without the added tag it was subject to 'main meta style' duping, with the "support" tag it's a request for staff (or less likely that a non-staff member) to look into this specific case; and if there's a general fix for everyone (something was broken) all the better. --- I understand you say there was a notification by comment and one expected from the system, neither of which was received. A CM on your site could look instead ...

Comment: @Rob As I understand it, everything described was "working as intended". The system intentionally does not send notifications when a post is deleted, so there's nothing for a CM to look into. OP is asking either for a better? different? explanation of why that is, and/or for the system to add notifications for that.

Comment: @EmC Working/NoMystery, just a request; dupes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314839/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172796/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107017/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80460/282094 and a means to find them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39741/282094 - find the closest and vote up or bounty, no need to duplicate "just a FR"; many would like to know more, rare it's not been asked for already.

Comment: @Rob, how meaningful would it really be to up vote or bounty a question that's almost 10 years old or even 2 years old? I've up voted most of those Q's and some A's, and one Q was even linked above in the Q. Part of the reason I've asked this Q is to bring to light how it's still an issue that's apparently been ignored or unsatisfactorily "resolved" for many years. The mere fact of this feature request being repeatedly posted and up voted demonstrates the unsatisfactory situation.

Comment: This post is far too long compared to my expectations when I read the title.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you're asking here. Is this a feature request asking to add notification when post is deleted? Is this a discussion asking to discuss why there is no notification? Please pick one, can't have both in a single question.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard, this was supposed to be discussion on why the feature request was never implemented, hopefully leading to it being implemented, due to the large amount of people apparently wanting it implemented.

Comment: Well, that's not how things work. Amount of users who want something never meant anything, SE has their own agenda and their own "review" process for bug reports and feature requests, for good and for bad.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard, well, using a polling system to determine features to implement is fairly standard now, and seeing as this site is essentially based on user polling, you'd think it'd be a natural thing to do. You'd also think feature request polling and deletion notification would be pretty easy to implement. Instead, we have holiday "hats", which seems to have been a lot of work to have implemented and apparently continually need fixing. I'm glad customer amusement is higher priority than customer usefulness in the eyes of SE/SO.

Comment: This struggle continues. I was linked here by this similar question/answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406964/13729