# I want to see all my Stack Exchange linked deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, feed

*Searching **"deleted:1"** yielded 217,625 results*.

I am not informed why my account is suspended. I have no question or answer history here:
*https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/83785*

**Solution idea: a "deleted" tag**. This would allow that tag to be searched or RSS albeit it's on a per-site basis as I think user IDs are not consistent on all sites.

I hate investing time into a question only to have it deleted and not being notified about it. But it seems like the site keeps the database entry, so I was wondering if I can grep/mget all my deleted posts.

*https://askubuntu.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/885719*. Maybe I can replace it like so:

```
$EXCHANGESITELIST . "/users/recently-deleted-answers/885719"

$EXCHANGESITELIST . "/users/recently-deleted-questions/885719"
```

and like flashGot.

But I wanted to ask you guys if this feature is implemented or perhaps I can set up an RSS feed to be notified.

Comment: You can't use `deleted:1` unless you have the ["moderator tools privilege"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), which is unlocked at 10,000 rep (or 2,000 on betas).

Answer (score 18):

> Im just wondering why my codegolf account was killed I even contributed a game concept tiny.cc/ZeVeRoH all history deleted on that site.

You did not *contribute a game concept*, you spammed the main and meta sites with questions and answers that contained nothing more than a poster and the URL of your website.

Most of your other posts were just nonsense. None of them was an appropriate question or answer.

> I have no question or answer history here.

The account you used to post that spam was deleted. You actually created a new account (which hasn't posted any questions or answers yet), but it got suspended automatically for the rule violations of the old account.

> I will never get mod priviledge because every post is negatives and I dislike this sites goals and design as to try an' ASScertain priviledges

If you want to contribute on PPCG, please check out [our help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and other users' posts, to see what we're all about and what proper questions and answer look like.

As you can see on your profile page, you're currently suspended for 7 more days. You're welcome to return after those 7 days are over.

Comment: No I think that site is about stealing ideas and SEO optimization.